# render function not rendering anything React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

Nothing is rendering on screen. No clue why its happening, No error anywhere. Wondering why nothing is showing on screen. Getting data from API properly. Code is given below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Grid, Row, Col } from 'native-base';
import axios from 'axios';
import ItemCard  from '../components/ItemCard';

export default class ItemHorizontalScreen  extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums').then(response => 
            this.setState({
                items: response.data
            }))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }

    renderHorizontalContents() {
        const rowItems = this.state.items
        rowItems.map((rowItem, index) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
                    <Text>{rowItem.title}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            {this.renderHorizontalContents()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to return something from your `renderHorizontalContents ` function. use `return rowItems.map((rowItem, index) => {...}`

Comment: good catch.. working now .. thanks a lot :) @nrgwsth

Answer (score 3):

Your `renderHorizontalContents()` should return the list:

```
renderHorizontalContents() {
    const rowItems = this.state.items
    return rowItems.map((rowItem, index) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
                <Text>{rowItem.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    })
}
```

Also, semi-related, as of React 16.3 React team advises not to use `componentWillMount()`. You should fetch the data in `componentDidMount()` LifeCycle hook.

More on `componentWillMount()` deprecation:

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1575

Answer (score 3):

Try this. The issue is renderHorizontalContents() is not returning so you have to return elements which map returns for you

Also regarding adding key, if items array contains unique id per object then use that is as key that is recommended. Index is always second option if you don’t have unique id from data. Also when adding index as key you should add something like I did below instead of adding index as key directly.

```
renderHorizontalContents() {
        const { items } = this.state;
           return items.map((rowItem, index) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={"Key"+index}>
                    <Text>{rowItem.title}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    }
```

Comment: you dont need the if, if you've got length its already an array so just wont loop over them

Comment: @JoeWarner Agree with you